# Strange behavior when going to Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have a blend file. I got it from [here](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/72367). A strange thing happens when you go to Edit Mode on "body" part. Well, the object called "body". Anyway, when you do that the half of the object is clipped, you go back to Object Mode, the clipped part goes back. I figured out that applying the existing subsurf modifier fixes this weird behavior. 
 And another thing. The origin point is cyan instead of orange.


Any thoughts on why this happens and what's with the origin point color? 
[Here's the file itself.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xdmmqrl29usumy/iPhone4S_final.blend?dl=0) (if you don't have an acc on blendswap) 
Edited:

- Thanks to Gonzou, his answer solves the mystery of the disappearing mesh.
- The cyan dot mystery still remains. I looked through theme colors and didn't find any entry that controls that cyan dot. The "Active Object" entry only controls the outline color on that object. However, on a newly created object an origin dot color is orange (as it expected) and that "Active Object" entry controls an outline and dot colors.

Comment: BlenderSpot, you may ask a question about the cyan origin problem. I am very curious about why it happens.

Comment: @Gonzou, you mean as a separate one?

Comment: Yeah, why not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The half of the 'body' mesh is just hidden. You have to unhide it. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. The cyan point may be the matter of changed settings in *'User Preferences'* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).